# Como insertar un SP en masivo para varias base de datos desde un SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, insert, mssql

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo en ver mi consulta. ¿Cómo insertar un procedimiento almacenado en varias Base de Datos MSSQL', todo ejecutado con un sp.

Comment: Existen demasiadas formas de hacerlo, tal vez podrías dar un poco de trasforndo (por que, para que, recursos disponibles) acerca de lo que quieres hacer para dar las mejores opciones.

Comment: Gracias, lo que pasa es que he realizado una modificación de  un SP. Obviamente que una manera es ejecutar de manera individual un ALTER PROC SP_PROCESO... en cada Base de Datos. Pero para hacerlo de manera masiva, que con un SP, función o proceso pueda realizarlo para varias bases de datos, evitando el trajín de lo comentado anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

**Nota importante**: Todo el código debería ser manejado desde un control de versiones como git, subversion o CVS y después usar Jenkins, Octopus o Azure Studio para implementar el código a distintos destinos. Sin embargo, esto requiere de un trabajo más amplio para su implementación.

Una de las maneras más claras de hacerlo sin un control se versiones, es usando los servidores registrados en SSMS. Lo primero que debemos hacer, es mostrar la pestaña de servidores registrados desde el menu Ver.

[image: Mostrar Servidores Registrados]

Después creamos un grupo que serán todos los destinos en los que se ejecutará el script.

[image: Crear grupo de servidores]

Dentro de ese grupo, creamos un servidor registrado.

[image: Crear servidor registrado]

Es importante hacer notar, que debemos de crear un servidor registrado por cada base de datos. Y en cada servidor registrado debemos ir a las propiedades de conexión para indicar la base de datos a la que se conectará.

[image: Conectar a base de datos]

Una vez que tengas todos los servidores registrados dentro del grupo, puedes darle clic derecho al grupo y seleccionar Nueva Consulta. Eso hará que cualquier código que ejecutes desde ahí se ejecute en todas las bases de datos que configuraste.

[image: Nueva Consulta al grupo]